# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at lab3.Lab3.readTestScore(Lab3.java:93) at lab3.Lab3.main(Lab3.java:25)

Tags: java, arrays

```
package lab3;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3 
{

    static int n;
    static double testScores[] = new double[n];
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int studentID;

       System.out.println("Enter student ID: ");
       studentID = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter number of test scores");
       n = input.nextInt();

       readTestScore(n);

      //double[] testarray = readTestScore(n);
      //System.out.println("Test Scores are:" + testarray);

    }
    public char getLetterGrade(double score)
    {
        char letter;
        if(score >= 90)
        {
            printComment('A');
            letter = 'A';
        }
        if(score >= 80)
        {
            printComment('B');
            letter = 'B';
        }   
        if(score >= 70)
        {
            printComment('D'); 
            letter = 'C';
        }   
        else if(score >= 60)
        {
            printComment('D');
            letter = 'D';
        }
        else if(score < 60)
            printComment('F');
            letter = 'F';

        return letter;
    }
    static void printComment(char grade)
    {
        if(grade == 'A')
        System.out.println("COMMMENT\t\t\t:\t" + "Very Good!");
        if(grade == 'B')
        System.out.println("COMMMENT\t\t\t:\t" + "Good!");
        if(grade == 'C')
        System.out.println("COMMMENT\t\t\t:\t" + "Satisfactory.");
        if(grade == 'D')
        System.out.println("COMMMENT\t\t\t:\t" + "Needs Improvement.");
        if(grade == 'F')
        System.out.println("COMMMENT\t\t\t:\t" + "Poor.");


    }
    static void printTestResults(double []testList)
    {

     for(int i = 0; i < testList.length; i++)
     {

         System.out.println("Test Score\t\t\t" + "Letter Grade\t\t\t" + "Comment\t\t\t");
        System.out.println(testScores[i] + "\t\t\t" );//+ getLetterGrade(score) + "\t\t\t" + printComment(grade));

     }  
    }
    static double[] readTestScore(int size)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i =0;
        System.out.println("Enter Test Scores:\t");
        for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
        testScores[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
       testScores[i] /=n;
       System.out.println("these are test scores: " + testScores);
        return (testScores);
    }   
}
```

Comment: need help understanding why i get this error message. tried taking anything that was initialized with null or zero out.

Comment: So? what is the question? This is what you get when you try to access the first element of an empty array.

Comment: i try to run the program and when it gets to readTestScores(); i enter n which is the number of test scores i want to enter. but once it gets to the function it gives me the error above.

Comment: singhakash has already provided a response pointing out the error. You declared an array with 0 elements, and are trying to access its first element.

Answer (score 2):

Because of this

```
static int n;
static double testScores[] = new double[n];
```

array is set to default size of int ie 0 giving you that error in the method

Comment: Quick catch - you beat me to it :)

Comment: @andrescasado define its size inside the method

Comment: @alfasin this is not even 1% of how many times you beat me in the past :)

Comment: @singhakash my sincere apologies :) I would upvote again as a compensation but I already did because... it was a good & quick catch :)))

Comment: testScores = new double[(int)size]; ive tried to initialize this inside readTestScores. is this what you mean?

Comment: sorry for all the questions just taking a crash course in java

Comment: that works but now that i have to input n test scores do i just pass n to the function? how do i get to input more than one value into the array?

Comment: double test = 0;
     System.out.println("Test Score\t\t\t" + "Letter Grade\t\t\t" + "Comment\t\t\t");
     for(int i = 0; i < testList.length; i++)
     {  
         test =+ testList[i];
        //double final = test/testList.length;
        //+ getLetterGrade(score) + "\t\t\t" + printComment(grade));
     }
     double result = test / n;
     System.out.println(result);

Comment: i changed a few things

Comment: my code looks like this now i can enter scores and it will return but when i try to print results it only divides by the last number entered into the array

Comment: @andrescasado atleast give some running code and why do you use 2 scanners use only one http://ideone.com/4Hehvr